# How to install Caffe2 with Anaconda Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, caffe2

According to the site of [Caffe2](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=windows&configuration=compile), Python 3 support for Caffe2 is still experimental. I want to use Caffe2 with Anaconda Python 3.6. How to do install Caffe2 successfully in this scenario? Both `pip install caffe2` and `conda install caffe2` have failed. In the former case, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.setup_helpers'`. I have installed pytorch, but the error still remains. I need to install Caffe2 in Windows 10 and I don't have any NVIDIA GPU.

Another interesting point is that, [MNIST Tutorial of Caffe2](https://github.com/caffe2/tutorials/blob/master/MNIST.ipynb) is written in Python 3. So there has to be Python 3 support for Caffe2 to run the code of this tutorial.